# Set programmatically product sale price and cart item prices in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

This is the continuation of : [Set product sale price programmatically in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763989/set-product-sale-price-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3)

The answer works, however once a user adds the product to cart, the old price still shows up on checkout.

How to get the correct sale price on cart and checkout pages for cart items?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing part to get it work for for cart and checkout pages (and also Orders and email notifications too) is a very simple trick:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_sale_price', 20, 1 );
function set_cart_item_sale_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_sale_price(); // get sale price
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); // Set the sale price

    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.

> So the code just set the product sale price as the product price in cart items and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code is helpful for you

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'bbloomer_alter_price_display', 9999, 2 );

function bbloomer_alter_price_display( $price_html, $product ) {

  // ONLY ON FRONTEND
  if ( is_admin() ) return $price_html;

  // ONLY IF PRICE NOT NULL
  if ( '' === $product->get_price() ) return $price_html;

  // IF CUSTOMER LOGGED IN, APPLY 20% DISCOUNT   
  if ( wc_current_user_has_role( 'customer' ) ) {
    $orig_price = wc_get_price_to_display( $product );
    $price_html = wc_price( $orig_price * 0.80 );
  }
  return $price_html;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'bbloomer_alter_price_cart', 9999 );

function bbloomer_alter_price_cart( $cart ) {

  if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

  if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 ) return;

  // IF CUSTOMER NOT LOGGED IN, DONT APPLY DISCOUNT
  if ( ! wc_current_user_has_role( 'customer' ) ) return;

  // LOOP THROUGH CART ITEMS & APPLY 20% DISCOUNT
  foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $price = $product->get_price();
    $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price * 0.80 );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@LoicTheAztec answers works very nicely, but is not required.

You need to filter at least **woocommerce_product_get_price** and **woocommerce_product_variation_get_price** with the dynamic_sales_price_function.

To make it work really smoothly, you need some more filters as well.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me.
Here is what worked:

```
function get_active_price($price, $product) {
        if ($product->is_on_sale()) {
            return $product->get_sale_price();
        }
        return $product->get_regular_price();
    }

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'get_active_price'));
```

This worked with custom sale and regular prices.