# Display variation prices per month in Woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have three subscription products, yearly, half-yearly and monthly. By default, prices are shown per year, per every 6 months and per month on my Shop page.

Based on *"[Change product prices via a hook in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3/45807054#45807054)"* answer code, I am trying to display all the prices per month, so to change the price display based on the subscription term:

```
// Utility function to change the prices with a multiplier (number)
function get_price_multiplier($var_product) {
    switch($var_product) {
        case 111:
            // Annual
            return 12;
            break;
        case 222:
            // Semiannual
            return 6;
            break;
        case 333:
            // Month
            return 1;
            break;          
        default:
            return 1;
            break;
    }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    $var_product = $product->get_id();
    return $price / get_price_multiplier($var_product);
}
```

This worked but when a product is added to the cart, the price is not the regular price but the modified price from the function above.

Based on *"[Set programmatically product sale price and cart item prices in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771178/set-programmatically-product-sale-price-and-cart-item-prices-in-woocommerce-3/48771273#48771273)"* answer code, I have been able to fix that:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_sale_price', 20, 1 );
function set_cart_item_sale_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $regular_price = $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price();
        $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( $regular_price * get_price_multiplier($variation_id) );
    }
}
```

This reset the cart price and it seems to work although one of the prices is off by a penny.

Is this all convoluted and prone to problems or is it a solid way to achieve what I am after: to show the price per subscription term on the shop page?

Comment: I would like to display the subscription variation prices on the Shop page like I described without having to modify the price. If I can't do that, then the question is am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it in the right way… There is 2 ways (the last is the best one):

> **Note:** The calculation and the price change is not needed when the multiplier is equal to 1.

**1) First alternative:** Improved code version that is very similar to yours.

Here is my commented code:

```
// Utility function that increase conditionally the variation price with a multiplier (int)
function get_variation_calculated_price( $variation_id, $price, $multiplier = true ) {
    switch( $variation_id ) {
        case 111: // Annual
            $rate = 12;
            break;

        case 222: // Semi-annual
            $rate = 6;
            break;

        default: // Month (and others)
            $rate = 1;
            break;
    }
    // Return calculated price (or false when multiplier is 1, as calculation is not needed)
    return $rate !== 1 ? ( $multiplier ? $price * $rate : $price / $rate ) : false;
}


// Change variations calculated prices
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $variation ) {
    if( $new_price = get_variation_calculated_price( $variation->get_id(), $price, false ) )
        return $new_price;

    return $price;
}

// Customizing cart item prices
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_sale_price', 20, 1 );
function set_cart_item_sale_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Required since Woocommerce version 3.2 for cart items properties changes
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop  through cart items
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Only for variations
        if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ) {
            if( $new_price = get_variation_calculated_price( $cart_item['variation_id'], $cart_item['data']->get_price() ) ) {
                $cart_item['data']->set_price( $new_price );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

2) Second Alternative: much more accurate and lighter, restricting the product price avoiding price change on cart, checkout and backend.

> **Note:** You will need to avoid displaying Cross-sells products in cart page (as the prices will not be changed like in shop page).

So the code will be more light, compact and efficient:

```
// Utility function that increase conditionally the variation price with a multiplier (int)
function get_variation_calculated_price( $variation_id, $price ) {
    switch( $variation_id ) {
        case 111: // Annual
            $rate = 12;
            break;

        case 939: // Semi-annual
            $rate = 6;
            break;

        default: // Month (and others)
            $rate = 1;
            break;
    }
    // Return calculated price (or false when multiplier is 1, as calculation is not needed)
    return $rate !== 1 ? $price / $rate : false;
}


// Change variations calculated prices
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $variation ) {
    // Not in cart, checkout and admin
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() || is_admin() ) 
        return $price;

    if( $new_price = get_variation_calculated_price( $variation->get_id(), $price ) )
        return $new_price;

    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the updated code. There's one problem, when the subscription is for 1 month, i'm getting a price of 0.

Comment: @YourBudWeiser Sorry there was an oversight when I have made some changes… It's updated and works for 1 month subscriptions now (with no price calculation).

Comment: @YourBudWeiser I have added a 2nd much better alternative to my answer… Please try it.

Comment: Yes the 2nd function works, just needed to change is_checkout to is_checkout(). Also, the price in the cart is off by 1 cent for the annual and seminannual price. Otherwise, super code!