# Set cart item product generated sale price only for specific products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, price

Following [Set only specific products sale price programmatically in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52558815/set-only-specific-products-sale-price-programmatically-in-woocommerce-3/52562803#52562803), the related cart items price are not updated with the product's generated sale price.

How can I get the generated sale price for specific products, in the related cart items?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right generated sale price in cart item for specific product IDs try the following:

```
// HERE below in the array set your specific product IDs
function specific_product_ids(){
    return array(37, 41); //  <===  <===  <===  <===  Your Product IDs
}

// Generating dynamically the product "regular price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_regular_price', 'custom_dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_regular_price', 'custom_dynamic_regular_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_regular_price( $regular_price, $product ) {
    if( ( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 ) && in_array($product->get_id(), specific_product_ids() ) )
        return $product->get_price();
    else
        return $regular_price;
}


// Generating dynamically the product "sale price"
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_sale_price', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
    $rate = 0.8;
    if( ( empty($regular_price) || $regular_price == 0 ) && in_array($product->get_id(), specific_product_ids() ) )
        return $product->get_regular_price() * $rate;
    else
        return $sale_price;
};

// Displayed formatted regular price + sale price
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_dynamic_sale_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_dynamic_sale_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) return $price_html;

    if( in_array($product->get_id(), specific_product_ids() ) ) {
        $price_html = wc_format_sale_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ), wc_get_price_to_display(  $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_sale_price() ) ) ) . $product->get_price_suffix();
    }
    return $price_html;
}

// Set cart item generated "sale price" for specific product IDs
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_sale_price', 10, 1 );
function set_cart_item_sale_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array($cart_item['data']->get_id(), specific_product_ids() ) ) {
            $price = $cart_item['data']->get_sale_price(); // get sale price
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( $price ); // Set the sale price
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks again! it worked
I'll try some more things but in the meantime thanks for your help!